# Select rows where two words occure in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "comments"

```
ID  Comment
1   This is a test.
2   Hello.
3   I am a test.
4   How are you?
```

And out of a textfile I read the following string:
"Today i am going to run a test."

What I want to do is to select the rows that contain at least two of the words of my string. In this case I want to select row 1 and row 3.

I tried using the FULLTEXT search but it outputs even rows with only one word appearance in the row. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a function ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a good way of doing this in SQL.  One method is to parse the string and then count the number of matches:

```
where ((concat(' ', comment, ' ') like '% Today %') +
       (concat(' ', comment, ' ') like '% I %') +
       (concat(' ', comment, ' ') like '% am %') +
       (concat(' ', comment, ' ') like '% going %') +
       (concat(' ', comment, ' ') like '% to %') +
       (concat(' ', comment, ' ') like '% run %') +
       (concat(' ', comment, ' ') like '% a %') +
       (concat(' ', comment, ' ') like '% test %')
      ) >= 2
```

You can do something similar with full text search, using the boolean search capabilities.  Note however that full text search has a minimum word length and stop words list.  This would eliminate almost all the words in your sample string.

Comment: The problem is, the text I read out of the text file is different every hour. In content and in length. So it's really hard to do it with the full text search.